# Conditional probability : what is $\mathbb P(F)$ for $F:$" power supply fluctuate".

Tags: probability

Here's the statement:

> Quality control in a factory detects that 8% of the produced items are class $B$ quality only (i.e. not flawless). With a probability of 4% the production line functions suboptimally due to pollution, and with 50% probability the material used has quality issues. If pollution occurs, the items are class $B$ with a probability of 10%. Technicians also find that if there are fluctuations in the power supply then there is 10% probability that the product is class $B$. Based on these data, calculate the probability that power supply fluctuates.

I really have difficulty understanding the statement. As I see the problem: Let $P$ be the event "pollution", $Q$ the event a quality defect, $F$ the event "power supply fluctuate", and $B$ the event "$B$ quality".

I see the problem as follows. (see picture below).

[image]

So we just have 
$$x=\mathbb P(F)=1-0.04-0.5=0.46?$$ 
But I don't use $\mathbb P(B)$. So maybe it should be $$\mathbb P(B)=\mathbb P(P)\mathbb P(B\mid P)+\mathbb P(Q)\mathbb P(B\mid Q)+\mathbb P(F)\mathbb P(B\mid F)$$
which is equivalent to $$x=\frac{0.01}{0.1}=0.1,$$
could it be possible?

Comment: I've posted something below.   A couple of caveats:  first, I made some assumptions (spelled out at the start) which you might or might not have intended.  second, the computation (while logically straight forward) is arithmetically unpleasant and error prone.  I advise checking it carefully, line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that the external factors (pollution, low quality, fluctuations) occur independently.  I'll also assume that these are all the external factors.  That is to say, if we find a Class $B$ item then we know that at least one of those external factors was present.  Let $\Phi$ denote the desired answer (the probability that fluctuations occur).

Let's use $\Phi$ to compute the probability that an item isn't in Class $B$.  Since we know that to be $.92$ we can then solve for $\Phi$.  We'll denote the three externals by $P,LQ, F$ and for any of those externals we let $X^c$ denote their complement.  We'll go type by type.

Type $(P^c,LQ^c,F^c)$.  The probability of this state occurring is $.96\times .5\times (1-\Phi)$ and, of course, no item of this type is in Class $B$.

Type $(P^c,LQ^c,F)$ The probability of this state is $.96\times .5\times \Phi$ and an item in this state is in Class $B$ with probability $.1$, hence it is not in class $B$ with probability $.9$

Type $(P^c,LQ,F^c)$  The probability of this state is $.96\times .5\times (1-\Phi)$ and an item in this state is outside Class $B$ with probability $.9$

Type $(P,LQ^c,F^c)$ The probability of this state is $.04\times .5\times (1- \Phi)$ and an item in this state is outside Class $B$ with probability $.5$

Type $(P^c,LQ,F)$ The probability of this state is $.96\times .5\times \Phi$ and an item in this state is outside Class $B$ with probability $.9\times .9=.81$

Type $(P,LQ^c,F)$ The probability of this state is $.04\times .5\times \Phi$ and an item in this state is outside Class $B$ with probability $.5\times .9=.45$

Type $(P,LQ,F^c)$ The probability of this state is $.04\times .5\times (1-\Phi)$ and an item in this state is outside Class $B$ with probability $.5\times .9=.45$

Type $(P,LQ,F)$ The probability of this state is $.04\times .5\times \Phi$ and an item in this state is outside Class $B$ with probability $.5\times .9\times .9=.405$

Thus we get the (somewhat unpleasant) linear equation:

$$.48\times (1-\Phi)\times 1+ .48\times \Phi\times .9+ .48\times (1-\Phi)\times .9+ .02\times (1-\Phi)\times .5+ .48\times \Phi\times .81+\cdots $$ 
$$\cdots +.02\times \Phi\times .45 +.02\times (1- \Phi)\times .45+ .02\times \Phi\times .405=.92$$

And if no errors have been made (a big if, I grant) this comes to $$\Phi=\frac {110}{931}\approx .11815$$

Note:  the above is badly error prone so I strongly advise checking each stage carefully.

A simpler version:  Let's only consider the three events $E_P,E_{LQ},E_F$ where, for an external variable $X$, $E_X$ denotes the event "$X$ is present and causes the item to be in Class $B$."  Then we easily compute $$P(E_P)=.04\times .5=.02\quad P(E_{LQ})=.5\times .1=.05\quad P(E_F)=\Phi\times .1$$  Then the probability that an item is not in class $B$ is $$.92=(1-.02)(1-.05)(1-.1\times \Phi)$$

Which again implies $$\Phi=\boxed {\frac {110}{931}}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You have used $\Phi$ twice : for the fluctuation and for not be in $B$... is it a mistake ? Also, I don't really understand why my second method is not working, could you give me a reason ? (except that it's not working ^^)

Comment: I only use $\Phi$ to denote the fluctuation probability.  Assuming independence, I just use $\Phi$ to get the known probability, $.92$, that a random item is not in Class $B$.  I couldn't follow your method, I'll look again.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it, you mean $\Phi=\mathbb P(F\mid B^c)$ ?

Comment: Ok, the problem with your second method is that you don't address overlap between the external factors.   If you assume that the factors are mutually exclusive you can find a simple solution along your lines, but that assumption seems badly unrealistic.

Comment: $\Phi$ is the probability that fluctuations occur.  It says nothing about Class $B$.

Comment: In any case, it's critical that you say how the factors overlap.  You appear to have  assumed they were mutually exclusive though, as I say, that seems badly unrealistic. (why should the materials used have anything to do with power fluctuations, for instance?).  I assumed they were independent which strikes me as more plausible, though of course it too might be wrong.  Of course, if they have some complex dependency then we can't answer the question without knowing more.

Comment: Note:  mutual exclusivity is incompatible with the data.  We know that there is a $.5\times .1=.05$ chance that quality issues produce a Class B item.  We also know that there is a $.04\times .9=.036$ chance that pollution does.  If these were mutually exclusive events then the two factors would together make for a $.05+.036=.0836$ chance of a type $B$ item...but that is bigger than $.08$ so there must be some overlap.

Comment: Note:  I edited my post to include a greatly simplified version of the calculation.  This version isn't particularly error prone.

Comment: thank you very much for all your comments. I'll read them with attention and let you know if I need more help.

Comment: I'd suggest just looking at the simpler version.  I left the old one up for comparison.  The idea is the same, but the computational approach of the second method is much, much simpler.